# Getting Wrong incremental value

Tags: c#, .net-core

Below is my code. Here i am trying to increment values by 0.1 and after 0.5 it make a whole value and the increments goes. but while running the code i am getting decimal beyond added value.

```
double value1 = 1.0;
double minorvalue = 0.1;
int count = 0;
double output = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    double _over;
    if (count < 5)
    {
  
        _over = output + minorvalue;
    
        output = _over;
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        _over = (output + value1) - 0.5;
       

        output = _over;

        Console.WriteLine(output);
        minorvalue = 0.1;
        count = 0;
    }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

And the output is like below

```
0.1
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.4
0.5
1
1.1
1.2000000000000002
1.3000000000000003
1.4000000000000004
1.5000000000000004
2.0000000000000004
2.1000000000000005
2.2000000000000006
2.3000000000000007
2.400000000000001
2.500000000000001
3.000000000000001
3.100000000000001
3.200000000000001
3.300000000000001
3.4000000000000012
3.5000000000000013
4.000000000000002
4.100000000000001
4.200000000000001
4.300000000000001
4.4
4.5
5
5.1
5.199999999999999
5.299999999999999
5.399999999999999
5.499999999999998
5.999999999999998
6.099999999999998
6.1999999999999975
6.299999999999997
6.399999999999997
6.4999999999999964
```

don't know what's wrong with this incremental gives value like this 2.3000000000000003 and others 10.299999999999999

Comment: The problem is related to double precision. You may either display *outputToString("0.##")* or use "decimal" instead of "double".

Comment: tried ToString('0,0') too. confusing part if it is precision 0.1 even if it is read as 0.1000000 where comes 5.1
5.199999999999999
5.299999999999999